# Unable to delete from isolated storage

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-8

I m having a project in which i m trying to share my files on Sky drive from isolated storage.
Every thing is working fine but as per my requirement i have to delete my files after sharing.
when i try to share two file consecutively using

```
BackgroundUploadAsync();
```

this method.

It is giving an exception that is "Unable to delete file".

Can any one give some suggestions, or m i missing something here.

Thank you

Comment: Can you post some more code showing how you manage the deletion and how you call the BackgroundUploadAsync?

Comment: My best guess would be that the upload is still in progress and therefore still has the file open, try awaiting the BackgroundUploadAsync().  Another possible reason is that the BackgroundUploadAsync() implementation is not closing the file correctly.

Comment: @Peter: your guess is exactly right .but i cannot await the process because i m using it in WP7 app. if you have done this any way.. plz provide a sample code.

Comment: @Mahima apologies, I should have noticed you were on Windows Phone 7.  I'm not sure how BackgroundUploadAsync() is implemented, but usually if you have an async method (pre async/await) pattern you should have either an event that fires on complete or a callback method/action.  Did you implement the BackgroundUploadAsync() or is it 3rd party?